# Lock that can be transferred from one thread to another

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, atomic, semaphore

I am looking for a type of lock where the thread that holds the lock can pass it on to another thread of its choosing.

Here is why I want it:

- I have a class similar to `ConcurrentHashMap` - a specialized collection that is divided into multiple segments
- Most modifications require only one segment to be locked.  A few require two segments to be locked (specifically, modifying a key so that it moves from one segment to another.)
- Most reads do not require locking - a volatile read is usually sufficient, but occasionally a search needs to lock all segments at once, if a modification-count check fails
- Searching is done in multiple threads (via a `ThreadPoolExecutor`)
- It is essential that the search function has a consistent view of all segments (e.g. it must not miss an entry while it is being moved from one segment to another.)
- The search task (for a single segment) may be interrupted at any time.

Now I am considering the situation where the search method has been called in the main thread and discovers it needs to lock all segments.  All of the segment locks must be held at once by the main thread (to ensure there is no interference) but it is not the main thread that will be doing the updates - it is one of the worker threads.  Hence I am trying to make the main thread "pass on" the locks once it knows it has a consistent snapshot.

We used to use a single lock for the whole collection but as it got larger there was too much contention and unacceptably high latency for small updates.

Unlocking and re-locking (on a `ReentrantLock`) is not safe - another thread may modify the segment before the worker thread starts the search.

A plain `Semaphore` can handle locking and unlocking by different threads.  The issue that then arises is who should release the semaphore - the worker thread needs a way to signal that it has taken ownership of the lock (because it may throw an exception before or after this point and the main thread needs to know whether to clean up.)  It would also be tricky to unit-test because you never know if a semaphore acquire or release has occurred in the correct thread.

It would be a bonus if the lock could be used reentrantly in other methods (where it is not passed between threads.)

I imagine some combination of a `Semaphore` and an `AtomicBoolean` or `AtomicReference` is called for, but a quick google search did not reveal any examples.  Is there any reason why this approach should not be used?

Comment: Concurrency works best with simple model. Given the length of your description and the complexity of your model I suggest you try to simplify your requirements. IMHO its much more likely to work efficiently. The only method I know wakes a specific thread is Unsafe.park() and Unsafe.unpark(Thread) but I wouldn't recommend using these directly.

Comment: If all you want is a "lock" which can be passed on why not use a token passing mechanism, with each segment lock as a token, with it literally being passed on? If the collection search time is long enough this token can even be a file, file acting as lock. Main thread can simply give the "lock" to worker thread.

Comment: Is it possible to model this in a lock-free manner by having persistent structures with associative "updates" creating new structures rather than modifying in place? Your description is of a solution rather than the underlying problem you're solving so its hard to suggest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inverted use of a read/write lock may work. In this idiom, the read lock holders perform concurrent writes to the data structure (e.g. independent slots in an array). The write lock is used to acquire exclusive access to perform a consistent read (e.g. summing the array). This is a rarely used idiom, but elegant in those oddball cases. Your problem is a bit hard to grok, but this may at least offer some inspiration for a concrete solution. I suspect with a deeper understanding, the problem could be simplified so that a classical solution is more appropriate.

Comment: As I said, reading the source of `ConcurrentHashMap` may make it clearer.  My class is very similar except that when it does the equivalent of `contains(Object)` it searches each segment in a (potentially) different thread.  I will see if I can tweak the question to make it clearer.  I think your solution will work though.

Comment: I understand the technical aspects, but not the behavioral ones. Why is a key moved? Why do you have to search (e.g. why not use a ConcurrentSkipListMap)? What is the contract that makes it different than a normal map?

Comment: there is no single natural ordering of keys.  This search operation does "fuzzy" comparison and must check every element in the segment looking for the few closest matches.  Modifying a key occasionally changes its hashCode such that it belongs in a different segment.  I must move it atomically to ensure it is not left out of a search while it is being moved.

Comment: Okay - then versioning is the classic solution to this. This is done using a persistent data structure or a replica where the transactions (put/remove/move) are replayed (e.g. updates submit to a write queue). The latter could support concurrent searches by using a reader/writer lock, where the writer lock is acquired when there are pending updates to replay. Either would allow the search to not block other writers, whereas the inverted read/write lock would be blocking (but could check and yield to minimize this).